# JavaFX Creates Daemon Threads called "Timer-XX"

Tags: java, javafx, mp3, media-player

I just recognized that my program creates a `Daemon Thread` every time I play a MP3. And they're are Named "`Timer-XX`" as everybody suggest yes XX is a increasing integer starting with zero.

Ok I can understand that `JFX` needs them to play a MP3 but actually the MP3 is just 3 sec long and some of them stay `Running` for a couple of minutes or longer, while others normaly run out (i just suggest it should be like this).

I would like to know why they get created in the first place? Why they stay `Running` and how I can get ride of them because as far as I know `Daemon` dose not mean stopped so it still eats Memory and CPU what I can't give away like candy in the current state of my project.

Here is the code that plays the MP3s:

```java
public class EffectPlayer {
    private final String MP3_SUFFIX = ".mp3";
    private final static int MAX_VOLUME = 100;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private int masterVolume = 50;
    private int effectVolume = 50;

    public EffectPlayer(File f){
        if(isMP3(f)){
            Media mp3 = new Media(f.toURI().toString());
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(mp3);
            effectVolume = Integer.parseInt(GetConfig.getVar("USER_OPTION_VOLUME_EFFECT"));
            masterVolume = Integer.parseInt(GetConfig.getVar("USER_OPTION_VOLUME_MASTER"));
            if(effectVolume > masterVolume) effectVolume = masterVolume;
            mediaPlayer.setVolume(1 - (float)(Math.log(MAX_VOLUME - effectVolume) / Math.log(MAX_VOLUME)));
            mediaPlayer.setCycleCount(1);
            mediaPlayer.play();
        }
    }

    private boolean isMP3(File f) {
        return f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(MP3_SUFFIX);
    }
}
```

The JFX Panel gets created in the class that Creates a EffectPlayer Object

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
```